# Logo not displaying in excel

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel template with a logo at the left-top and an empty table after that. I am using java to generate an output excel file based on that template with filled table data. But in the output excel the  logo is not getting displayed. Instead of the logo I am getting this :

[image]

Any fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checked the path of image file. Check if image path is accessible from excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that could correct that issue: In the Start menu, go to All Programs, then Accessories, then 'System Tools'. From there type 'Folder Options'. In the View tab of the dialog, clear the checkbox for "Hide extensions for known file types". Select OK.

To fix the icons, try repair Office. In the control panel, go to  Programs & Features, right-click Microsoft Office(YEAR)-select Change. When the wizard opens, click on the Repair options, then press Continue.